# Why does my Android button not work?

Tags: android, eclipse, button, navigation

I am trying to get a simple button to work to navigate between screens, I'm really not sure what I've done wrong, as I followed a guide!

First page code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button aButton;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 } {
 aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.scales); 
 aButton.setOnClickListener( {;new OnClickListener();
}
public void onClick(View v){
Intent i = new Intent(mainactivity.this, buttons2.class); startActivity(i);
} }
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.xx"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.xx.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
              android:label="MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="Buttons2" android:label="Buttons2"></activity>

     </application>

</manifest>
```

Code for second page:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Buttons2 extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.other);
} }
```

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Try to remove the ; before new in aButton.setOnClickListener( {;new OnClickListener();   --> aButton.setOnClickListener( {new OnClickListener();

Answer (score 1):

Try to reformat your code. There are way to much brackets.
It should work this way:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.scales); 
    aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent i = new Intent(mainactivity.this, buttons2.class); 
          startActivity(i);
       } 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're problem appears to be in your `onCreate` method. You are closing the `onCreate` with } and then trying to find the button via `findViewById`. Since this is not contained within a method it is never called. Try something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.scales); 
aButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
     public void onClick(View v){
         Intent i = new Intent(mainactivity.this, buttons2.class);
         startActivity(i);
     }); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MainActivity blocks have serious troubles :o

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button aButton;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.scales); 
        aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Buttons2.class); 
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the onCreate() of your MainActivity is the problem. It should look like this.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.scales); 
 aButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener();
 tb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Buttons2.class); 
      startActivity(i);
    }
 });
```

Also make sure that activity_main.xml has a Button with

```
android:id="@+id/R.id.scales"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to write this before `findViewById();` in your case. and make the following corrections:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button aButton;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         aButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.scales); 
         aButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()

        public void onClick(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(mainactivity.this, buttons2.class); 
        startActivity(i);
        });
    }
}
```

Rest of the thing is correct.